# jQuery plugin "whatweather" showing all days, in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a question for the jQuery Plugin "whatweather" from [getkode.be](http://getkode.be/whatweather/whatweather-documentation/)

I have installed it and its running fine, now im looking at the layout, and i have some issues.

If I wan't to display all week days i use this code, but it's hard to changes the layout 100%

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $("div#whatweather").whatWeather({
     id: "",
     city:"Billund,Denmark",
     days:"5",
     refresh: 0,
     dateFormat:"{{DD}}",
     weekDays:["Søndag","Mandag","Tirsdag","Onsdag","Torsdag","Fredag","Lørdag"]
 });
</script>
```

So i get this

[image]

If I then add a Template like this code.

```
<div id="whatweather"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var template =  '<div class="{{cssClass}}">\
         <p class="current">\
             <span class="climacon {{currentWeatherIcon}} temp-pic"></span>\
             <span class="city">{{city}}  {{currentCondition.temp}}°</span>\
         </p>\
         <div class="next-days">\
             {{#nextDays}}\
             <div>\
                 <p>\
                     <span>{{date}}</span>\
                     <span class="climacon {{dayWeatherIcon}} temp-pic"></span>\
                     <span>{{tempMax}}°</span>\
                 </p>\
             </div>\
             {{/nextDays}}\
         </div>\
 </div>';

  $("div#whatweather").whatWeather({
     id: "",
     city:"Billund,Denmark",
     days:"5",
     refresh: 0,
     dateFormat:"{{DD}}",
     weekDays:["Søndag","Mandag","Tirsdag","Onsdag","Torsdag","Fredag","Lørdag"],
     templates: [template]
 });
</script>
```

Then I get this

[image]

But after 1-2 sec. the "Next days" disappear, so I get this.

[image]

Do someone know how to make fix this little issue in the template code ?

Comment: I do not know how but `next-days` div got `display:none` style. From console, DOM elements: `<div class="next-days" style="display: none;">`. That means day list is not visible. Manually unchecking that style in console retrieved day list back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define option `cssClass`. Because of that you got default value which is `widget-1`. From the code of this plug-in:

```
templates: ['<div class="{{cssClass}}">\
...
    <div class="next-days" style="display:none">\
...
```

That is the reason that your days data are hidden.

If you want to get them shown, you have to follow instructions written [in documentation page](http://getkode.be/whatweather/whatweather-documentation/). See example after sentence *Voici le code pour obtenir ce widget.* You have to define:

```
 function myAfter(el, options){
    el.on("click", function(){
        $("p.current, div.next-days", el).toggleClass("transition");
    });
```

which toggle display of days on/off. And you have to add `after` and `cssClass` option, something like:

```
 cssClass:"whatWeatherMetro",
 templates: [template],
 after: myAfter
```

The last step is new css file. All is described there.

Comment: Hi Anto Jurkovic. Have looked at it, and have copy/past the default template frem the JS file and that works.